# Accidentally sent cryptocurrency to wrong address

Tags: cryptocurrency

I was exchanging cryptocurrency with Changelly when I noticed after the fact that I put in the wrong address.  I know I'm probably out of luck, but is there anything I can do to get it back?  I have no affiliation with this wallet address.  I have no idea how it even got in my clipboard.

Comment: Note that there is malware that checks your clipboard contents and substitutes a hacker-controlled address. It could be that your computer has been infected with such malware.  To check this, copy and paste some addresses and see if they were changed.

Comment: Oh good idea!  I’ll try that thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Crypto currency transactions are not reversible by design, and the addresses are anonymous, so you don't even know who to ask for the money back.

Comment: Right, I just didn’t know if someone had a method to figure out what happened and reverse it.  Or maybe this was a common issue changelly was having.